# How to Insert the UITextView into UIAlertview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertview

Also, I would like this UITextView with the text file in XXX.txt.It works fine in iOS6, but content does not appear on the UIAlertview in iOS7. my code is given as below:-

```
UITextView *tosTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 48, 260, 140)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TJTermsof Service"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
[tosTextView setText:content];

tosTextView.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
tosTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LuzSans-Book" size:17];
tosTextView.editable = NO;
customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@" TOS \n\n\n\n\n\n " message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"I Agree",nil];



[customAlert addSubview:tosTextView];

[customAlert show];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following link has resolved my problem, the link is https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

the following content has resolved

1. textview
2. tableview
3. ImageView
4. UIWebView

both functionalities are worked as fine for me

Answer (score 6):

This should work. Give it a shot. But it's a hack and might not be appreciated by Apple.

```
UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:@""
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))//For Backward compatibility 
{
    [testAlert addSubview: textView];
}
else
{
    [testAlert setValue: textView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}
[testAlert show];
```

Comment: How to get the textview value?

Comment: @Gank, you will have to create an outlet for the textview if you need to use it. valueForKey:@"accessoryView" does not seem to work. But for lesser than iOS7 SDKs, you can get all the subviews from an alert view.

Comment: @KoushikKumar can you explain more about how to create an outlet for the textview?

Comment: @KoushikKumar How can I add placeholder in textview?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify the alert view view hierarchy in iOS7.

You need to either roll your own implementation of an alert view, or use an open source implementation, such as [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView).

Comment: I dont need the Thirdparty

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Then you can't implement.

Comment: any other idea, if its possible

Comment: If you do not want to use a custom alert view, implement your own. Or display the text view in a modally presented view controller.

Comment: Why do you not want the open source implemented alert view?

Comment: every code, I write down in programatically, bz i m in 2 mnth wrkng exp, I need to learn, i am child in iOS

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using open-source. Even better, take a look at the code and you will learn something new.

Comment: HMM,U r the senior, u said correctly, K friend, I use the the SDCAlertView.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this myself.

By default UIAlertview content is a textview. How large you are giving the content UIAlertview will definetly present it in a textview.

I think you have given the text in Alertview title. You should have given it in the message.

[image]

Comment: tanx buddy,but text file contains some form format,so that s y i asked

Comment: u given the output is directly insert the some text content into UIalertview, but i need the attached txt file into the textview and the texview is insert to the subview of UIAlertvie,

Comment: Ok Got you. Then the best is push it in a new ViewController with a textview. If you are going to show a file then viewcontroller with UItextview is the best option.