# Create a Custom UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

After reading this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics--mobile-8886) on `UIAlertView`, I have an important unanswered question: how is the actual function of a `UIAlertView` working in terms of its presentation and dismissal? For example, if I want to simply subclass `UIView`, add a `UIButton` that says "Dismiss", what would be the best way to show this `UIView` and to dismiss it when this button is pressed?

Comment: try this it is useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios7

Comment: UIAlertView's been deprecated. Use UIAlertController instead. Plus, it makes what you're trying to do easier than before.

Comment: @LyndseyScott thanks for the tip. How customizable is UIAlertController though?

Comment: If you want a UIView to act as a custom Alert view, you need to specifically set constraints or frame of your custom UIView with respect to the parent view, create a custom class for your custom view add delegate properties to communicate with the parent view.