# How to make a UIView that looks exactly like UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview, appearance

I want to show some labels on the screen and I want to make them look exactly like UIAlertView. How can I copy the appearance? Note that I don't care about any of the functionality of the alert view and just want the default appearance as it looks good.
Common properties such as backgroundColor on UIAlertView is not set and also the properties of the CALayer don't show anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: use protocols or try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios7

Comment: You want to show alert dialog? why not using UIAlertView? Do you want to have a form with appearance of UIAlertView and instead of textbox only add labels on it?

Comment: @HBizhi No I don't want to show alert view I want to show some labels on the screen but I want to make their background look like the one used in UIAlertView. It's not a simple white color with an alpha value it looks kind of different and I want that.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried things like this: [uialertview appearance].backgroundColor but they don't return useful values and the link is all about customizing UIAlertView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is a Blur Effect.
If you're target is iOS 8 and higher, you can use this to create blur views

```
UIBlurEffect* blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
    effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];
    effectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    effectView.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:effectView];
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html)

Note that you can use UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight, UIBlurEffectStyleLight, UIBlurEffectStyleDark.

If you use a lower version of iOS, you've to use a custom class like [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).

Comment: That was it, thanks. In your answer change initWithEffect: part to initWithEffect:blur

Comment: Sorry ^^' I'll edit it. I took it from my code a changed the wrong line :p

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not the precise answer to your question, here are some open source alternatives to UIAlertView that would have let you do what you needed in first place.

https://github.com/rtecson/RTAlertView#Installation

https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView

There's probably a lot more too.