# Creating UIAlertView with multiple images and text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I want to create a UIAlertView with multiple images hoe can i do so.
I am attaching a sample image for my requirement.
[image]

Can someone give directions to implement this.
 I can design a simple Alertview controller with a image but don't have idea about multiple images

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios7) help you

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view with your images which looks like a `UIAlertView`, or use one of the custom alerts from the wonderful iOS Github community.

- **[Custom iOS AlertView](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)**
- **[DTAlertView](https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView)**

Answer (score 0):

You can *subclass* the `UIAlertView` to make it support images array.
Then in the -drawRect method, you customize the generation for the alert with the images from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

[ARAlertController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aralertcontroller)

Hope it helps.