# How can I Add TextField & CheckBox into the same AlertView

Tags: ios, checkbox, uiview, uialertview, textfield

I've added CheckBox into AlertView now I'd like to add `TextField` too into the same `AlertView`.

```
UIAlertView *alertForExistingCredit = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];         
rememberButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
[rememberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PortraitPhoto_Checkbox-Normal.png"]
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rememberButton setTitle:@"Save Code" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rememberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleRememberMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];            
alertForExistingCredit = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PrePay Code"
    message:@""
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:kCancelMessage
    otherButtonTitles:kAlertOkMessage, nil];
[v addSubview:rememberButton];
```

If I use:

```
//plain text part
//            alertForExistingCredit.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
//            [[alertForExistingCredit textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"PrePay Code"]; this lines of code it is not showing on the screen

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40);
       rememberButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 250, 50.0);
        [rememberButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        alertForExistingCredit.message = @"Please insert your PrePay code";
        [alertForExistingCredit setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"]
    }else {
        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 250, 40);
        rememberButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 250, 40.0);
        alertForExistingCredit.message = @"Please insert your PrePay code";
        [alertForExistingCredit addSubview:v];
    }
    alertForExistingCredit.tag = 0;
    [alertForExistingCredit show];
}
```

Comment: As clearly stated in the documenting of [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) you should not change the view hierarchy. So you will need to create your own view that you will display and should not use `UIAlertView`

Comment: Use a custom view, and probably a 3rd party alert view from github

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios7) may be help you

Comment: Do you have any other solutions guys?

Comment: Please share the screen shot of expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this UITextField to your v (UIView), and try to adjust frame size and location.

```
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 250, 50)];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        textField.delegate = self;
        [v addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add add a subview into your `UIAlertView` and put your buttons into that view, see the code to add a `UIView` into your `UIAlertView`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
[alert setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
// add your button in *view*.
[alert show];
```