# How could I create a UIAlertController with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a requirement to show an action sheet as shown in this image.[image]

```
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                                              message:@""
                                                                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


 UIAlertAction* share = [UIAlertAction
                                           actionWithTitle:@"Share via iCloud"
                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                           {
                                               [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                           }];
            UIAlertAction* create = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Create Document"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];

            [share setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Help_Bar_Icn"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
            [create setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Help_Bar_Icn"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];

            [alert addAction: share];
            [alert addAction: create];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have used UIAlertViewController with set value image but in this way the image is shown on left side.Could anyone help me,is there any default control like this as shown in iOS Pages app.Thank You

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? you said that you already had the code to show image on right side of the alert.

Comment: @Mr.T -- assume that this scenario  the questioner taken the some sample image from another app

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios

Comment: I have updated the code which I have tried, this code displays the image on left side only,My requirement is image on right side as shown in the image.

Answer (score -1):

you can't customize default **action sheet** like your image. For this purpose you have to customise a tableview as an action sheet.

for this you have to implement **Protocol**

Comment: provide you email address

Comment: Is using tableview the best solution?

Comment: I would also like to get an idea to do this. It will be great if you post an answer with sample code.@Mr.T

Comment: @TejaNandamuri r u got answer for this?

Comment: tomorrow, i will give you a solution, insa-allah