# UIAlertController / UIAlert with option / select button?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to enhance the Alert view to support
an option / select button.  However, it sounds like
this kind of feature goes against Apple policy of 
leaving native alert dialogs as-is.

Is there any best practice on how to raise a popup / alert
with an option / select button with a list of choices?  Should
I just create a new ViewController for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a customView which emulates `UIAlertView` but allows your specific requirements.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios