# How do I add margins to UITextField in a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently implementing a UIAlertController with text inputs. I successfully made it without any issues. However, I want to change how it looks and especially add margins between textfields.

[This is how it looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veaao.png)
[image]

However I don't want these text fields that close. The question is, how do I add margins to textfields?

My code and attempt:

```
func createNameChangeSheet(){
        var tvName : UITextField?
        var tvSurname  : UITextField?

        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "action", message: "alertView", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
            self.changeNameSurname((tvName?.text)!,surname: (tvSurname?.text)!)
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        sheet.addAction(saveAction)
        sheet.addAction(cancelAction)
        sheet.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
            tvName = textField
            textField.text = self.name

            let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 30, right: 0)
            textField.layoutMargins = margins
        }

        sheet.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
            tvSurname = textField
            textField.text = self.surname
        }
        self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true) {}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in default `UIAlertController` views are not customizable, if you need customize output then we need to go for customviews or any [thirdparty lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios)

Comment: Guess I will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to set bottom margin , make a UIView and addSubview to UITextField you can  make an extension to use throughout the application.

```
extension UITextField  {
 func textbottommboarder(frame1 : CGRect){
    let border = UIView()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  frame1.width, height: 2)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border.layer)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
 }
}
```

and than use it on UITextfields

```
txt_username.textbottommboarder(txt_username.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for something easier to implement since its not that high priority. I will try it when I get the chance.